# Return root url when sending ActionMailer email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, actionmailer

I'm trying to set up my ActionMailer so that it will read the URL it is being posted from. When this application is deployed, it could end up on many different servers with different domain names. Instead of having the user go into the code and force enter the URL statically, I would like the reset password url to include the domain that it was generated from (including http:// or https://).

I've tried `::Rails.root`, `request.host_with_port`  and `::Rails.root_path` within the Mailer, but none have produced results. `request.host_with_port` generates an undefined method error.

```
  def reset_password_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "#{::Rails.root_path}/password_resets/#{user.reset_password_token}/edit"
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Your password has been reset")
  end
```

Comment: Please run `rake routes` and show us the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you call `reset_password_email(user)` from one of your app controllers.

You can update this method definition and send with user the current host and port to it:

```
def reset_password_email(user, request)
  @user = user
  @url  = "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/password_resets/#{user.reset_password_token}/edit"
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Your password has been reset")
end
```

Don't forget to update your Controller's code.

Comment: +1 It's actually using the `sorcery` gem. I am using `#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}` with my other mailer in the controller.